# C# WPF MVVM Controlling mediaplayer position with slider makes audio stutter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm

For starters, as for now, everything else works perfectly. So I have a project what includes a music player part (a mediaplayer). Position is visualised by text and with a slider, and that's where my problem is. When I make the slider "draggable" (so I can set the position, not just get it) the media (.mp3) starts to stutter randomly. Here is the part of the code:

```
public double ElapsedSeconds
    {
        get
        {
            return mediaPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds;
        }
        set
        {
            //mediaPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value);
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ElapsedSeconds)));
        }
    }

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ElapsedSeconds = mediaPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds;
        TextContent = String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2:mm\\:ss}/{3:mm\\:ss}", playedArtist, playedTitle, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ElapsedSeconds), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TotalSeconds));
    }
```

ElapsedSeconds is binded to the value of the slider.
I can only drag the slider (and create the problem) when I uncomment that 1 line

And here is what I already tried:
- I used private field to store data
- Tried to use miliseconds and ticks but it got worse
- Tried to change the dispatchertimers tick frequency (currently 100 ms) what refreshes the current value

Is there any way to make the stuttering go away? (and if yes, what is it)

p.s.: If anyone interested, here is the whole .cs file: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/profgyuri/DJ-Tool-2/blob/master/DJ-Tool-2/ViewModel/MultitaskVM.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not thinking on the problem for almost 2 weeks I found a solution. Just need a condition to when to set the Position (so I changed the commented line to these):

```
if (mediaPlayer.Position > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value + 1) || mediaPlayer.Position < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value - 1))  
            mediaPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value);
```

Although at least 1 second of change is required, this way the program ignores the milisecond rollbacks what cause stuttering, while the Slider is still draggable.